# I have activated my account but cannot get my gpu all regions increased?

Tags: gcloud

I want to try two things in google cloud.

1. Nested virtualization to create bunch of simple office computers with gpu support (nvidia grid).
2. Premptible render nodes and AI training nodes , to work with some fault tolerant algorithms.

I have activated my account. Requested more GPU all regions increase. Mailed to the support. Tried to chat with technical support.

-- Mail delivery subsystem error. gc-team@google.com

-- Chat did not start, circle swirled forever

What should I do ?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a different browser.

Comment: I am using google chrome on linux ubuntu 18.04 fully udpated stable versions.

Comment: Have you followed [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota)?

Comment: Yes I followed it 2 times. My request denied via mail which also redirected me to google clout team mail which resulted in Mail delivery subsystem error. gc-team@google.com.

Comment: If your request was denied there's nothing Stackoverflow community can do.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza Its clear that there is nothing you can do. However question asks about the ways to contact them. There is no indication about any denial of any request. Inference is just an inference not the fact.

Comment: The only way to increase your quota described at the documentation I mentioned above. Also, you can try to contact [sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact). Are you a new GCP customer? Have you tried to request 2 times less resourses?

Comment: I have contacted the sales. They have redirected me to a solution partner. As I understand in my region they wont increase gpu quotas unless you have sub-Id of a solution partner. And yes I have followed the documentation as best as I can. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have been informed, in some regions, google cloud prefers opening gpu's and some services through their solution partners. I have contacted sales, arranged a meeting. In this meeting, they redirected me to a solution partner. We signed a reseller contract, prices and services are same unless you ask for additional value-added support from local reseller. They gave me a sub-id and registered my company domain and e-mail to gcs. Everything works now.

Bottom line I get from this is:

If you wanna get serious with google cloud you may want to contact sales directly.